Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 405 for URL
I use (java) HttpURLConnection to get Response from my remote server.
    URL url = new URL(URL_STRING);
    HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
    connection.setDoOutput(true);
    DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());

    Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
    params.put("param1", "value1");
    out.writeBytes(ParameterStringBuilder.getParamsString(params));
    out.flush();
    out.close();

    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
    String inputLine;
    StringBuffer content = new StringBuffer();
    while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
        content.append(inputLine);
    }

    connection.disconnect();
    System.out.println(content);

I get this message:
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 405 for URL: http://xxx

when i call the url in browser i get the answer

That's Method Not Allowed. And coming from the server.

the method is a GET method and i get the answer via the browser.

I believe GET is the default, but I don't see connection.setDoOutput(true);. You need that. Can you post a reproducible example?

Hi Elliott, i have posted the full code to reproduce the error. you could try the code.

For a get the parameters are part of the URL. You can't post parameters with a get.
